# Automating FFmpeg/ multi-core support

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I need help with FFmpeg/batch. I have a couple of large batches of images (+14000 files each batch, +5 MB each image, .TIFF all of them) and I'm stringing them together into a .mp4 video using FFmpeg.

The date in the metadata is broken because of the way they're stored upon creation, so the time and date (T/D) are on the file_name. I need each frame to have its respective T/D (so its File_Name) burnt onto them for accurate measurements (scientific purpose).

With the help of google and reddit, I've managed to semi-automate it like so:

Master.bat:

```
forfiles /p "D:\InputPath" /m "*.TIFF" /S /C "cmd /c C:\SlavePath\slave.bat @file @fname"
```

Slave.bat:

```
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -vf "drawtext=text=%~2: fontcolor=white: fontsize=30: fontfile='C\:\\FontPath\\OpenSans-Regular.ttf'" "D:\OutputPath\mod_%~1"
```

Running `Master.bat` will output each individual image with the text burnt onto them and change the File_Name to `mod_'File_name'.TIFF`

Real example: 2018-06-05--16-00-01.0034.TIFF turns into mod_2018-06-05--16-00-01.0034.TIFF

The problem is that FFmpeg doesn't like it when my files have "--" in them ("date--time.miliseconds.TIFF") **and** doesn't like the miliseconds either, so I have to change the name of all files "manually" using Bulk Rename Utility (BRU). So, using BRU I rename all files to `00001.TIFF, 00002.TIFF,` etc. and FFmpeg likes me again. It works great, but it means I can't be AFK.

After that, I have to go back to cmd and manually start the image to video conversion.

Also, FFmpeg doesn't seem to be using all cores.

---

I need help finding a way to:

1. Change `master.bat`'s output to `00001.TIFF` etc. automatically in order of processing (i.e. first to be processed is 1.TIFF, 2nd is 2.TIFF)
2. Add ffmpeg's img-to-vid function to the automating system
3. Get my CPU to use all the cores effectively if possible. 2014/15 posts found on google make it seem as though FFmpeg doesn't support multi-core or hyperthreading.

---

*64bit Windows, i7 7700hq, gtx 1050 4Gb, C: SSD, D: HDD*

Comment: add -threads X, where X is number of CPU core

Comment: Tried that, found no change. Tried -threads 0, 2 and 4.  I found no difference. CPU usage still at +-30%, D: disk at +´60%, RAM 20%... Where's my bottleneck!? :(

Comment: Do you have access to a machine running Linux?

Comment: I do, that's why I got batch and bash confused :/ but its a 2013 iMac and works abysmally slower than the PC I'm currently on. Why did you ask? Should I get ubuntu (or any other linux os)?

Comment: maybe tiff encoding is not multithreaded, so you must run slave.bat group by group

Comment: What do you mean group by group? ATM it's starting a new "instance" of FFmpeg for each image. Couldn't it be set so that each core runs one image instead of all images being processed by one core? And tiff encoding: does that mean that I could make it put out (say) a .jpeg and it would be able to multithread?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> ffmpeg -i "2018-06-05--16-00-01.%4d.TIFF" -threads 4 out.mp4

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence